# How to delete multiple images from firebase storage at a time in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I’m using android studio with firebase, Is there a way to delete multiple images at a time from firebase storage for android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API for bulk or batch deleting files in Cloud Storage.  You will have to delete each one individually as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/delete-files).

Answer (score 1):

In one of my project I used below code to delete multiple files

```
  const imageURLS = !Array.isArray(item?.data?.imageURL)
    ? [item?.data?.imageURL]
    : item?.data?.imageURL;

  imageURLS.forEach(async (URL) => {
    let storageRef = projectStorage.refFromURL(URL);
    await deleteFile(`images/${currentUser.uid}/${storageRef.name}`);
  });
```

Comment: Its better to explain the code you post in an answer.